# Go downtown? Tour the southland? Go under the hood?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In American TV show "Californication" S1E1 there's a dialogue below which I can't understand.

The woman said:

> "My husband never gave me an orgasm."

and the man asked:

> "Never? Does he, uh, you know, go down town? Tow the southland? No? Go under the hood?"

Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: It means "Does he ever perform cunnilingus on you?"

Comment: I'm sorry, but more specific please?

Comment: The woman claims that her husband has never stimulated her to orgasm, and the man asks whether her husband has ever performed oral sex on her. All three references "down town", "tour [not tow] the southland", and "go under the hood" are jocular references to a woman receiving oral sex from her partner. I can't get more specific without pictures.

Comment: @deadrat: perhaps Scion11 was asking you to be more specific on *how* the cunnilingus was performed ;-)

Comment: @Chappo I'll ask the moderators to migrate to sexualtechnique.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Scion11 - What about "perform cunnilingus" is vague? Are you asking for pointers on technique?

Answer (score 1):

**"go downtown"**, **"tour the southland"** and **"go under the hood"**, are slang phrases meaning to perform [**cunnilingus**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cunnilingus) i.e., to perform oral stimulation of the clitoris or vulva.

Assuming it is performed in all corners of the world, we would expect a list of synonymous slang words and phrases to be very long and impossible to produce. From [**The Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=on%20line) and [**The Online Slang Dictionary**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+cunnilingus.html) I can cite the following:

- **go down on**
- **dine at the Y**
- **tip the velvet**
- **eat a furburger**
- **eat a peach**
- **eat fur pie**
- **eat some clams**
- **have a box lunch**
- **munch on**
- **square away**
- **muff-diving**

Obviously these are all vulgar and whoever uses them should know exactly when and where it's acceptable, in addition to who they are talking to.

Comment: You forgot "**muff-diving**"!

Comment: People have used that expression for like 40 years, to my knowledge.  Back in the '80s, many of my peers used phrases like the ones mentioned.

Comment: Ok, ok, @RoyC. I will edit.